# How can I keep the vlcj player from taking up all the room?

Tags: java, swing, vlcj, jsplitpane

I am writing a small Swing program which involves embedding a video player in the interface. In order to achieve this, I am using vlcj.

While the GUI itself has some more components, here is an analog code structure:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyTestClass extends JFrame {
    public MyTestClass(){
        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerCmpt = 
            new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        playerCmpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JPanel leftPane = new JPanel();
        leftPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        JSplitPane mainSplit = new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            leftPane, playerCmpt);

        this.add(mainSplit);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyTestClass();
    }
}
```

<sup>(I tried this code separately, and I'm facing the same problem as in my GUI)</sup>

Basically, the window has two parts: a left panel in which I display some data, and a right panel in which the video is to be embedded. The panels are put together in a `JSplitPane` is order to allow the user to allocate the amount of room he desires for the player (and therefore, for the video itself). At first, the components get 100 and 200 pixels in width, respectively.

The problem is: `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` is getting a little too confortable.  While I have set it to a preferred size of 200x100, it refuses to shrink down once the vertical split has been moved. That is, I can't bring the player below 200 pixels in width, and once I've enlarge it, I can't bring it back to 200 pixels... Setting a maximum size doesn't change anything. This little problem is annoying because it forces my left panel to shrink again and again, until it becomes practically invisible.

Is there any way I could have the media player follow the constraints set by `JSplitPane` as the user tries to resize the components? If it's any use, the left pane contains a `JTree` in my application, which also gets crushed by the player.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Work this out using a `JComponent` in place of the VLC component. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me. Just improve the code to fit for your purpose.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;


public class MyTestClass extends JFrame {

    public MyTestClass() {
        String vlcPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC";

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcPath);
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerCmpt = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        playerCmpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JPanel leftPane = new JPanel();
        leftPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        playerPanel.add(playerCmpt);

        JSplitPane mainSplit = new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            leftPane, playerPanel);

        playerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

        this.add(mainSplit);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyTestClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: The key thing here is to put the vlcj player component inside the center of a BorderLayout panel, right, rather than adding it directly to the splitpane?

Comment: @caprica The key is the `setMinimumSize` call. Somewhere in the instructions above that, VLCJ must have set an enormous minimum size, which is cancelled with `.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));`. This explains the whole behaviour indeed, thank you d_air ;) I set a small minimum size too (after setting up the player), and the problem disappeared.

Comment: vlcj does not set any such enormous minimum size.

Comment: @caprica If you add a property change listener to the split pane, you'll see that whenever the divider grants more space to the player, its minimum size is increased so as to make any shrinking impossible. Whether this is done by Swing, vlcj or something else is beyond me though. However, this behaviour does not seem to occur with any other component. After this test though, I'll agree the setting doesn't involve an "enormous" size. It's simply set to the new size.